# Add Values of Checked Form Fields & Add Together To Insert Into Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that sends the values to insert into the database.  Here's the form:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "
    SELECT
      a.*,
      b.*
    FROM b_report_week a INNER JOIN b_report_expenses b
        ON a.ID = b.ID
    WHERE a.TASK_ID = $taskid
");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $invoiceID = $row['ID'];
    $mondayBill = $row['MON_BILL'];
    $tuesdayBill = $row['TUE_BILL'];
    $wednesdayBill = $row['WED_BILL'];
    $thursdayBill = $row['THU_BILL'];
    $fridayBill = $row['FRI_BILL'];
    $weekTotal = $row['MON_BILL'] + $row['TUE_BILL'] + $row['WED_BILL'] + $row['THU_BILL'] + $row['FRI_BILL'];
    print "<input type='checkbox' name='rep[]' value='$invoiceID'>Reference Number: $invoiceID<input type='hidden' name='weektotal' value='$weekTotal'><br />";
}
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

What I want to happen is the values get inserted into one line the database.  However I want the week total for each checkbox to be added together and inserted into one of the fields in the database.

I currently have the insert as:

```
$sql="INSERT into b_sale_order (LID,PERSON_TYPE_ID,PAYED,PRICE)
VALUES
('s1','1','N','VALUE OF THE $weekTotal added together for each checkbox checked)";
```

So for example, the hidden field 'weektotal' provides a value for each checkbox.  Once the checkbox is ticked and the form is submitted they need to be added together and then inserted into the PRICE field.

I'm not sure how to add the checked values together to insert into one field.

Your help would be appreciated.

I've researched more and although this doesn't work, maybe somebody could point me in the right direction:

```
 $array = array($_POST['weektotal']);
 foreach ($array as $value) {
      $totalweek += $value;
 }
```

Then put the $totalweek in the VALUES section of the insert?

I've also tried:

```
$totalweek = array_sum($_POST['weektotal']);
```

But this seems to add all the values together and not individual for the checkboxes that are selected.  Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure whether going along the lines of:

     $array = array($_POST['weektotal']);
     foreach ($array as $value)
     {
          $totalweek += $value;
     }

I can't get this to work but is it down the right lines?

Answer (score 0):

so, change HTML to: `<input type='hidden' name='weektotal[$invoiceId]' value='$weekTotal'>`

now php

```
$sum = 0;    
foreach($_POST['rep'] as $inv_id){
    $sum += $_POST['weektotal'][$inv_id];
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. I've added another couple of areas that I have tried on the orginal post if you think you could shed any light on those?

Comment: so you want to store in db the sum of checked values? before question update I thought that you want to store all value one field.

Comment: @AndyNaylor I have updated my answer after your question update, please check this, its may help you!